# Getting Timer to start when actionable object is pressed, not at start of movie

Tags: flash, timer, actionscript-2

I am pretty new to this... trying to have a timer start on a simple racing game. I have the action directly on the object, (car), and want the timer to start when you first start hitting one of the action buttons on the keyboard, up down left right. Right now it starts as soon as the movie itself starts, in the first scene even. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Code on Car:

```
onClipEvent(load) {
speed = 0;
acceleration = 0.4;
speedDecay = 0.96;
maxSpeed = 10;
backSpeed = 1;
lap = 1;
totallaps = 3;
var fulllap:Boolean = false;

}

onClipEvent(enterFrame) {
if(Math.abs(speed) > 0.3) { 
    speed *= speedDecay;
}else {
    speed = 0;
}
if(Key.isDown(Key.UP)) {
    if (Math.abs(speed) >= maxspeed) {
        speed += acceleration;
        }
    }
if(Key.isDown(Key.DOWN)) {
    if(speed < 0.5) 
    speed = -2;
    else
    speed--;
}
    if (Math.abs(speed)> 0.5) {
    if (Key.isDown(Key.LEFT)) {
        _rotation -= 10;
     }
     if (Key.isDown(Key.RIGHT)) {
        _rotation += 10;
        }
    }
   x = Math.sin(_rotation*(Math.PI/180))*speed;
   y = Math.cos(_rotation*(Math.PI/180))*speed*-1;

   if (!_root.ground.hitTest(_x+x, _y+y, true)) {
   _x += x;
   _y += y;
   }else {
    speed -= speed*1.5;   
   }
```

}

onClipEvent(enterFrame) {

```
if (_root.checkpoint1.hitTest(this)) {
    if(fulllap){
        if(lap >= totallaps)
        _root.gotoAndPlay("end");
        ++lap;
        fulllap = false;
    }   
}
if (_root.checkpoint2.hitTest(this)) {
    fulllap = true;
}
_root.currentlap = lap + "/" + totallaps;

seconds = Math.floor(getTimer()/1000);
minutes = Math.floor(seconds/60);
tens = Math.round((getTimer()-seconds*1000)/10);

if(minutes < 10) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
}
if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
}
if (tens < 10 ) {
    tens = "0" + tens;
}

_root.totaltime = minutes + "." + seconds + "." + tens;
}
```

There is a scene that precedes this scene with a button to go to the game part. The timer starts as soon as the movie starts. I want it to start when the game is first starting to be played somehow.

Comment: Where is the bit that starts the timer?

Answer (score 0):

Use `mouseDown` events to replace the `enterFrame` events, since the [onClipEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/00000587.html) function is controlled by the name passed into it:

```
 onClipEvent(mouseDown) {
 ...
 }

 onClipEvent(mouseDown) {
 ...
 }
```